# Performace issue with Mellanox

Tags: mellanox

Trying to do performance test for Mellanox NIC with the traffic generated using IXIA.10G cable connects the  traffic generator and DUT systems.Sending the traffic using IXIA traffic generator tool at 10 G but the reverse traffic throughput received at IXIA is only 2G.Followed Performance optimization  steps described in https://fast.dpdk.org/doc/perf/DPDK_20_11_Mellanox_NIC_performance_report.pdf. Please provide suggestion for resolving the issue.

```
enter code here
ethtool -A interface1 rx off tx off
ethtool -a interface1
ethtool -a interface2
sysctl -w vm.zone_reclaim_mode=0
sysctl -w vm.swappiness=0
echo 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 > /sys/class/net/enp3s0f0/qos/prio2buffer
echo 250000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 > /sys/class/net/enp3s0f0/qos/buffer_size
IRQBALANCE_BANNED_CPUS=$LOCAL_NUMA_CPUMAP irqbalance --oneshot
cat /sys/class/net/interface1/qos/prio2buffer
cat /sys/class/net/interface1/qos/buffer_size
systemctl stop irqbalance
echo -1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_runtime_us
#setpci -s 03:00.0 68.w=3900
#setpci -s 03:00.1 68.w=3900
echo 1024 > /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
##mlxconfig -d 03:00.0 q | grep CQE
echo -e "\n\n*************(IF SET TO AGGRESSIVE PRESS n ELSE PRESS y)*************\n"
#mlxconfig -d 03:00.0 set CQE_COMPRESSION=1
##mlxconfig -d 03:00.1 q | grep CQE
echo -e "\n\n*************(IF SET TO AGGRESSIVE PRESS n ELSE PRESS y)*************\n" 
#mlxconfig -d 03:00.1 set CQE_COMPRESSION=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend tuning network parameter and understand if they could help further

- /proc/interrupts
- /proc/net/softnet_stat
- netdev_budget

Below article has lot for details on performance tuning for network stack
https://access.redhat.com/articles/1391433